# Python: How to append certain information from a CSV file onto an array

Tags: python, arrays, csv, append

How is it possible to append all the values from the first column of a CSV file onto an array.

Given the csv

```
Anas,5/1/2015,2.875
Jack,5/1/2015,33.925
Conk,5/1/2015,136.85
```

The array would be

```
['Anas', 'Jack', 'Conk']
```

Also would it be the same code if I needed a separate array with the second column's values?

This is what i have tried

```
for line in file:
    Data=line.split(",")
    FromFile=Data[0]
    questions=FromFile.append(line)
```

Comment: You can use [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: You might need to LOOP through the lines which are SPLIT into an ARRAY while APPENDing which INDEX of each column you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("example.csv") as f:
    allData = [line.strip().split(",") for line in f]

    firstColumn  = [data[0] for data in allData]
    secondColumn = [data[1] for data in allData]
    thirdColumn  = [data[2] for data in allData]
```

Comment: Thanks pal, i was just wondering if you knew how to do it the way i tried? thanks anyway